# How to restrict PHP web app access with one machine?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, security, authentication

Basically, I want to provide a web application (built in PHP, MySQL, Apache) to users with source code in case they don't have Internet connection. But with that, I have to take care that they web application package (with Apache, PHP, MySQL and actual application with data) cannot be copied and run in another machine (may be we can bind authentication with Hard Disk serial id).

The first solution stroked in my mind was to build stand alone application but we don't have that option because we have limitation to go with web application only.

One solution, I thought is to create a web browser like container (which may be using one of the system's browser inside) in Java or any other stand alone programming language where we have additional authentication for current machine and internally it uses system's browser for HTTP requests/responses.

Please share your idea about feasibility/implementation of above solution or any other better solution.

One thing to keep in mind that, we are providing all source code with servers, so authentication with database or PHP won't be much useful.

Comment: You could create a data container secured by a password/keyfile that is embedded in the compiled executable.

Comment: can you please explain in detail or provide some reference?
here data container is any term for specific language like java or  in general?

Comment: No I meant that in general. For example use a rar or 7zip archive and secure it with whatever you want, a password or what else is possible (I don't know exactly what is possible). Hide the password in the compiled executable and nobody will be able to access your files.

Comment: Might be worth a look: https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/

Comment: @halfer very cool. I need to keep track of this. Looks very promising

Comment: @halfer, it's really good but it doesn't support MySQL and we are using MySQL :-)

Comment: @MarcusRommel, sorry, I still don't get it. Do you mean, after storing password in zip file, authenticate with that password programmatically?

Comment: Well, carry on searching - maybe there is similar with MySQL - I remember seeing a similar server/browser app package on Github. Or maybe you can convert to SQLite.

Comment: I'm sorry, i try to clarify it a bit more. Just put all the stuff you need to protect in a secured container. Just like securing a zip with a password. Only you have access to this files because only you have the key to open it. And now you could implement this key into the compiled executable which makes it nearly impossible to get that password if you don't already know it. Through this only your application can open and execute the php (and all the other) files and your work is protected.

Comment: @MarcusRommel, Thank you for your idea. but we need one more thing to take care, which is, even if password is shared with someone else and other person copies source code in another machine then also it should not be authenticated. That's why we want to bind our web application with machine somehow.

Answer (score 0):

> But with that, I have to take care that they web application package (with Apache, PHP, MySQL and actual application with data) cannot be copied and run in another machine (may be we can bind authentication with Hard Disk serial id).

This is, strictly speaking, [impossible](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem).

> The first solution stroked in my mind was to build stand alone application but we don't have that option because we have limitation to go with web application only.

Have you ever heard of [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/)? [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/)? [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)?

Stand-alone applications can trivially be reverse-engineered. This will protect *nothing*.

Your best options are:

- Provide a cloud service, which is totally agnostic towards HTTP clients, so you can own the back-end machines that contain your source code, then give your customers a dumb open source front-end that speaks to the back-end.
- Enforce your software policies (i.e. only allowed to run one copy of the software) with the appropriate tool for the job: Lawyers and contracts.